# Spark as the storage layer for Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, caching, apache-spark, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I am facing a unique problem,  and wanted your opinions here.

I have a legacy map-reduce application, where multiple map-reduce jobs run sequentially, the intermediate data is written back and forth to HDFS. Because of intermediate data written to HDFS, the jobs with small data lose more than gain from HDFS's features, and take considerably more time than what a non-Hadoop equivalent would have taken. Eventually I plan to convert all my map reduce jobs to Spark  DAGs, however that's a big-bang change, so I am reasonably procrastinating.

What I really want as a short term solution is that, change the storage layer, so that I continue to benefit from map-reduce parallelism, but do not pay much penalty for storage layer. In that direction, I am thinking of using Spark as the storage layer, where map-reduce jobs will store their outputs in Spark through Spark Context, and the inputs will be read again (by creating Spark input split, each split will have it's own Spark RDD) from Spark Context.

In this way, I will be able to operate intermediate data read/write at memory speed, which will theoretically give me significant performance improvement.

My question is, does this architectural scheme make sense? Has anyone encountered situations like this? Am I missing something significant, which I should have considered even at this preliminary stage of the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate with examples of what you wanted to do in a step by step way. [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Ram, I want to employ some in-memory storage layer for the intermediate data my map-reduce jobs produce. Presently the map-reduce outputs are stored in HDFS, which is causing performance penalty in lieu of replication/distributed storage nature ( which I don't want to incur in some environments, e.g System Testing environment)

Answer (score 1):

> does this architectural scheme make sense?

It doesn't. Spark has no standalone storage layer so there is nothing you can use here. If it wasn't enough at its core it is using standard Hadoop input formats for reading and writing data.

If you want to reduce overhead of a storage layer you should rather consider accelerated accelerated storage (like [Alluxio](http://www.alluxio.org/)) or memory grid (like [Ignite Hadoop Accelerator](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.0/docs/hadoop-accelerator)).

Comment: Okay, what I meant by using Spark as the storage layer is to use Spark just for saving and loading data. So effectively, what it technically means is to create RDDs in mappers' map method, and then cache/persist the created RDD in the cleanup method. 

In the next job, read data from the cached RDD from the previous Job, and so on.

Isn't that technically possible? 

I have gone a little through Ignite Hadoop Accelerator, but wanted to eliminate other possible solutions first :)

Comment: RDD caching is a temporary mechanism for storing partial results of the intermediate computations. It is not a storage solution, it is not permanent, it doesn't even provide guarantees if data will be cached. It has no usage beyond Spark.

Comment: Thanks , both Alluxio and Ignite are making complete sense for my case!